# How can I work out a percentage cover of a polygon layer by another?

Tags: arcgis-pro

I am working with ArcGIS pro 2.2.0.

I'm trying to work out how much area is affected by some ocean exclusion areas, I have a grid of 10x10km squares and wanted to work out how much each square is affected by these exclusions.

This is my overall grid area: (red square is just showing location of the second image)

[image: Overall Area]

This is an example of the exclusions I want to calculate how much of each grid cell is affected by the exclusions.

[image: Example of Exclusions]

Comment: There's also a Tabulate Area tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that some of your exclusion areas could overlap. If this is the case, the first step is to dissolve them (with the dissolve tool). In any case, dissolving won't harm, so I suggest to use it anyway (except if you want statistics for different types of exclusion areas).

Then, you can use the "[summarize within](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm)" tool, which does what you need (with ADD_SHAPE_SUM set to true, which is the default).